# Spring Boot can't run single test in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, kotlin

This started happening recently, but I'm not sure what changed to cause it.

- When I run all tests from IntelliJ, all is well. Also the gradle build is fine.
- When I run a single unit test, all is well.
- When I run a single web integration test, it fails because a config class has all null properties.

The config class looks like (Kotlin):

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api")
public open class ApiConfigImpl : ApiConfig
{
```

A test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(ApplicationAssembly::class), loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader::class)
@WebIntegrationTest
open class CandidateProfileControllerTest
{

    @Inject lateinit var profileRepo: CandidateProfileRepository
    //etc a few more deps used to setup test data

    @Test
    open fun getById()
    {
        val greg = CandidateProfile("123", "12312", "Greg", "Jones",   dateOfBirth = Date(), gender = Gender.MALE,
            biography = "ABC", maxMatchableAge = null,   maxMatchableDistance = null)
        profileRepo.save(greg)

        val auth = given().header("content-type", "application/json")
            .body(testCredentials)
            .post("/authorization/social").peek().asString()
        val accessToken: String = from(auth).get("accessToken")

        given().header("Access-Token", accessToken).
            header("API-Key", testAPIKey()).
            get("/profile/${greg.id}").
            peek().then().
            body("stageName", notNullValue())
    }
```

I'm not sure what information I can add. Based on the limited information provided:

- Is this a known problem with a known solution?

Comment: Show us the single web integration test please.

Comment: there you go @miensol, thanks

Comment: thankfully it seems to work on IntelliJ 16 (EAP), which is good to go again, after solving this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35178407/404201

Comment: I suspect the problem you might be encountering is caused by differences in how gradle spring boot plugin and idea treat resources. You can verify that by checking if the single, now failing, test still fails after a Rebuild Project invoked inside Idea.

Comment: @miensol That certainly sounds plausible. I couldn't tell you with absolute certainty, because I went back to IntelliJ 15 (I've been using the 16 EAP) to verify your suggestion, and it has stopped happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, logged in the [IntelliJ/Kotlin tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10814), with a pending fix.