# Get IntelliJ Kotlin plugin and gradle to match up

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying IntelliJ 16, early access version, but my project won't compile with:

```
Error:(16, 17) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: substring
(note: this may be caused by the fact that some classes compiled with 
an incompatible version of Kotlin were found in the classpath. Such 
classes cannot be loaded properly by this version of Kotlin compiler.
```

Presumably the Gradle and IntelliJ versions of Kotlin need to match up, but the installed Kotlin plugin is: `1.0.0-rc-1007-IJ143-11`

I don't see this in any public repository. The latest one I have declared in the gradle project is:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = ' 1.0.0-rc-1007-IJ143-11'
```

. . can IntelliJ 16 be used with Kotlin and Gradle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, Kotlin IDEA plugin RC (`1.0.0-rc-1007`, `1017`, `1025`) is incompatible with Beta libraries, and RC libraries builds are not on Maven Central yet.

To use them, you have to add the EAP repository:

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/' }
}
```

to both `buildscript` and the project part.

Also, your `kotlin_version` is incorrect, it shouldn't have `-IJ143-11` part. Use `1.0.0-rc-1025`.

The other solution is to rollback Kotlin plugin to Beta version, which involves deleting it (`plugins` subfolder of IDEA installation, as it is preinstalled in EAP 16) and installing the Beta again from ZIP distribution.

To learn more about EAP builds, please refer to [this topic](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-early-access-preview-updated/1437).

---

## UPD:

The RC has been released along with the artifacts.

Comment: I used the second suggestion. When I upgraded gradle's kotlin to match intellij, it complained that a few dependencies (Kotlin module for jackson) were on older ABI.

Comment: There is a EAP build of that library @JasperBlues, and in the #eap channel on the Kotlin Slack chat are the specifics for the library release and temporary repo during the private EAP.    If you are in Slack, https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/eap/p1454443147000351 if not add maven repo `http://dl.bintray.com/jaysonminard/kohesive` and use the jackson kotlin module that best matches `2.5.5-RC-1025`, `2.6.5-RC-1025` and `2.7.0-RC-1025`

Comment: Thank you @JaysonMinard, I'll join the Slack channel. Would be happy to test EAP releases.

Comment: Erm. . is that a community Slack channel? How to join?

Comment: What does RC stand for?